# Calling Powershell From Jenkins Pipeline with parameters

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline which has a parameter that takes the branch name to build.
Then down the line i call a powershell script , i need to pass the parameter to this scrpit , but i am not able to do the same , i have tried the below options , please check and let me know if you have any inputs/suggestions.

i have tried with the below options already :

powershell script: 'C:\MSG-Team\Test_Automation\Message_Router\Scripts\Update_Config_Files.ps1 {branch}'

powershell script: 'C:\MSG-Team\Test_Automation\Message_Router\Scripts\Update_Config_Files.ps1 ${branch}'

powershell script: 'C:\MSG-Team\Test_Automation\Message_Router\Scripts\Update_Config_Files.ps1 {branch}'

powershell script: 'C:\MSG-Team\Test_Automation\Message_Router\Scripts\Update_Config_Files.ps1 ${params.Branch}'

```
node()
{   
    def build_ok = true
    def branch = params.Branch
    echo "The branch / tag selected to build is :" + branch

        stage('Pre-requisite')
        {
           powershell script: 'C:\\MSG-Team\\Test_Automation\\Message_Router\\Scripts\\PreRequisite_Actions.ps1'
        }

        if(params.Build)
        {
            stage('Build & Deploy Services')
            {               
                    try
                    {
                        echo "Stoping the existing services if any running"
                        powershell script: 'C:\\MSG-Team\\Test_Automation\\Message_Router\\Scripts\\Stop_Services.ps1'
                        echo "Stoping services Completed"
                        echo "Triggering deployment"

                        def Build_MSG_BOM_status               = build job: 'Build_MSG_BOM' , parameters: [string(name: 'Branch', value: params.Branch)]
                        def Build_MSG_Logging_status           = build job: 'Build_MSG_Logging' , parameters: [string(name: 'Branch', value: '1.0.5')]
                        def Build_MSG_LIB_status               = build job: 'Build_MSG_LIB' , parameters: [string(name: 'Branch', value: params.Branch)]
                        def Build_Message_Router_status        = build job: 'Build_Message_Router', parameters: [string(name: 'Branch', value: params.Branch)]

                        powershell script: 'C:\\MSG-Team\\Test_Automation\\Message_Router\\Scripts\\Install_MR_Service.ps1' 

                        echo "Deployment Completed"

                        echo "Updating Config Files"
                        **powershell script: 'C:\\MSG-Team\\Test_Automation\\Message_Router\\Scripts\\Update_Config_Files.ps1 ${branch}'**
                        echo "Config File Update Completed"


                    }
                    catch(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `def` keyword while declaring `branch = params.Branch` and substitute single quotes with double quotes while calling the `powershell` step.

```
powershell script: "C:\MSG-Team\Test_Automation\Message_Router\Scripts\Update_Config_Files.ps1 $branch"
```

Comment: I suspect that this is equivalent to `powershell -Command .\script.ps1` rather than `powershell -File .\script.ps1`; the former will not preserve the exit code of the script, but instead will return 1 if the called script has failed (return some code other than 0).